# How can I get rid of divider on android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar?

Tags: java, android, toolbar

How can I get rid of divider on android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar?

[image]

I have `LinearLayout` below `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`. They both have  the same color. How can I get rid of devider between them?

Comment: If you don't set it as the actionbar, it would have that line.

Comment: @EugeneH I haven't done that

Comment: Then you can inflate the menu manually.  toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_recipe);  And control the menu actions manually, toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener

Comment: Are you saying that you are not setting the toolbar as the actionbar?

Comment: @EugeneH It doesn't matter

Comment: Do you have dividers set in your `LinearLayout`, for instance: `showDividers:top`?

Comment: @questioner I haven't modified `LinearLayout`